# Bash wilcard expansion with command-line switch

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I am using a command that takes input of the form

`command [-a input_files]*`

So I can call `command -a foo` or `command -a foo -a bar -a baz`.

Now, I am trying to automate a workflow and would like to pass all files in a directory to the command. Is there a way to get a wildcard to do this? I know about `*` but this doesn't allow me to insert the mandatory `-a` prefix: `command *` would just execute `command foo bar baz`.

Is such an operation possibly natively in bash, or will I need to use sed, etc.?

Comment: Which command do you have in mind? Depending on the command, different handling may be required.

Comment: I'm using `lcov`, an instrumentation program.

Comment: I have come up with

`for f in *; do echo -n "-a $f "; done`, 

the result of which can be store in a variable and passed to the program. Better solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: In ZSH, this is done with `command *(P:-a:)`

Comment: xargs could be a solution but i don't have `lcov` or a program with `lcov` behavior to test it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the shortest way is to use printf:

```
lcov $(printf -- ' -a %s' *)
```

But it still might fail for some programs, please test and report back.

Comment: What are you thinking it might fail on? Strange filenames in the directory? I'm not particularly worried about this in my case because I am operating on a well-formatted and static directory, but would be interested to hear your thoughts on the general case. It works perfectly fine, for example, for filenames with spaces.

Comment: @baum It may fail for files with double (or more) spaces (or tabs), not only one, as the command execution is not quoted (affected by IFS splitting by the shell). And it probably will fail  for  files with newlines (a very infrequent issue).  No problems with multi byte names (utf8).

Answer (score 0):

Build up an array `args` that has `-a` ahead of every (`*`) file, then run `command` with the whole list:

```
for f in *
do
  args+=(-a "$f")
done
command "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: That will include directories (if they exist). And, maybe hint at the solution for a path with spaces (the question) using `for f in "$SOURCE"/*`.